How to redirect or show custom 404 for css and js folders in Laravel?
How can I redirect users to the website’s root or show a custom 404 page when they attempt to directly access the css and js directories under the public folder by entering a URL in the address bar? For example, visiting these URLs: https://example.com/css and https://example.com/js.
I'm using Laravel 10 with OpenServer 5 (Apache and PHP 8.1). I haven't changed any apache and php settings, everything is default from OpenServer.
When I try to visit https://example.com/css in my project, I get the error shown in the screenshot.

In Laravel, I've set up my routes so that when a user navigates to a non-existent route, they are redirected to the homepage (example.com/). This works as expected, but folders inside the public directory (such as css, js, fonts) ignore this behavior and instead return the error shown in the screenshot.
What I want is that if someone tries to access a route like https://example.com/css, they should either be redirected to the homepage (example.com/) or see a nice custom 404 page instead of the error from the screenshot. Can this be done using Laravel?

On real sites like dev.to or laravel.com, if you try to access
directories like dev.to/assets or laravel.com/build, they show a
clean 404 page, not the Apache error like in my case.

My .htaccess code:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>

Please be patient with me. I’m a complete beginner in development, and instead of making fun of me or acting condescending, please guide me on the right path.

Post the contents of your public/.htaccess file if you have one. Generally, Apache configs for apps that use a front controller will do something like, "first try the given url as a file, then try it as a directory, then fall back to the index page." If this is the case in your config, you can take out the "then try it as a directory" bit.

@AlexHowansky I updated my question by adding the .htaccess code

OK, it's been a while since I wrote any Apache rewrite rules and I'm no expert on Laravel routing, but I think you'll get the desired behavior by just commenting out the !-d line in this section:
# Send Requests To Front Controller...
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Then, if a request comes in for a name that happens to be a valid directory, then it will be handled by Laravel's router, which will do... who knows what with it. Hopefully decide it's not a valid route and serve Laravel's pretty 404 page. Note that this will prevent you from using directory-based URLs in the future, which may not be an issue.
Alternatively, you might add these two lines between RewriteEngine On and  # Handle Authorization Header:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

This says, "if the requested URL references a real directory, then stop processing rules and immediately reply with a 404." This will prevent the request from ever making it to your Laravel app, so you'll get the Apache 404 page, not the Laravel 404 page.

Thank you! It worked. Now when I specify the folder path, I am redirected to the main page (ie, the fallback I specified in web.php is triggered). If I remove the fallback from web.php, I get the standard laravel page with a 404 error (fine with me)

By default Laravel handle error pages and you can customize ur pages inside of your app.
First of all you dont need to run .htaccess file in your local server.
Second of all you haven't started your app correctly.
You suld up your laravel app with php artisan serve cli command
First way to run your app normally is running from openserver's console
opening console
console

Right-click on the OpenServer icon in the system tray.
Select "Open Console" (it will open a terminal window). Open Openserve's console
Then locate to your laravel project folder in the console
run cd domains
run cd <your-laravel-app-folder-name>
run php artisan serve

After running php artisan serve, the console will display the URL where your app is being served (usually http://localhost:8000 by default). Open this URL in your web browser to view your application

Thank you for your reply. It worked, but partially. Now I'm getting another error
https://ibb.co/nDmM8C3

@AnatolyLindemann Actually I dont suggest u to use Openserver cause of its not for begginers and it has detailed featues and coplicated for beginners. Try to use XAMPP and up your laravel app quickly.
By the way is there any specific reasons you use Openserver?

Just OpenServer up to version 6 is very convenient for beginners in web development. Just 3-4 clicks and the local server with the database is started. It is very convenient for local development. You don't need to customize anything additionally. In the new version of OpenServer 6 this concept has been destroyed and there is no point in using this application.

I had experience with Openserver for long time. Its good, I don't get in touch with new versions of it but its your choice. I recommend Xampp or Herd.
by the way, with other localhosts you don't even deal with such an htaccess problem and etc.
My personal choice about localhost is to use Herd and installing mysql manually that is all.
